# Возможно ли объединить несколько html-файлов?

Tags: html

Вопрос в том, каким образом так сделать, чтобы в проекте на продакшен был один html. Например, пользуюсь sass, у меня есть основной файл main.sass и какие-то по типу _reset.sass, _base.sass, _vars.sass. Надеюсь, это понятно. в продакшене у меня один файл со стилями получается. 
меня интересует такая система с разметкой. может, система там немного иная, но ведь во всех повторяется шапка и футер. хотелось бы как-то подобным образом подключать html и чтобы на продакшен он выходил один.

может я немного непонятно объяснила :D но вдруг

Comment: А чем вы собираете `sass` файлы?

Comment: есть куча `html` шаблонизаторов, все зависит от сборщика

Comment: можно воспользоваться [Server Side Includes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Side_Includes)

Comment: Погуглите pug, jade. Еще как вариант для много страничных статических сайтов возможно имеет смысл посмотреть на [middleman](https://middlemanapp.com/)

Comment: спасибо большое, ребята. 
собираю галпом

Answer (score 1):

для этого используется php. файл разбивается на 3 части например шапка сайта, подвал и главный файл, в котором в нужном месте вставляем шапку и подвал.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <?php include('header.html');?>
    Какой-то контент
    <?php include('footer.html');?>
</body>
</html>
```

при этом на сервере должен работать интерпретатор, который выполняет php код. если это локалка, то нужен локальный web server.

Comment: те кто минусы ставят, - обосновывайте сперва! или кайф просто так минус ставить?

Comment: скорее всего вы просто чуть чуть промахнулись ( речь ведь не шла про `php` ), но ваш ответ имеет право быть, минусы тут излишне, кмк

Comment: мне важны все варианты. я тоже против минуса

Answer (score 0):

Пользователь Shadow, всё верно написал.
Автор вопроса указывает только HTML, но для его целей нужен не только HTML, но и PHP.
Но так же можно использовать метод SSI:
 index.html

```
<body>
<!--#include virtual="/ost/header.html"-->
<!--#include virtual="/ost/main.html"-->
</body>
```

header.html (должен находится в папке ost по примеру)

```
<p> Хедер работает </p>
```

main.html (должен находится в папке ost по примеру)

```
<p> Основной Контент работает </p>
```

Comment: автор написала, что собирает галпом)

Comment: Ну так понятное дело, пока я писал, уже всё "устаканилось".

Comment: подождите. это не решает проблему, что я собираю галпом :D я впервые сталкиваюсь с тем, что у меня несколько html и для каждого свой стиль. и как по уму собирать их в 1 файл?